# Execute PHP script in background while logging errors

Tags: php

How can I run a PHP script in the background, without the web page hanging, while logging errors to a log file?

I know I can use this command, `exec("php -f background.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");`, but this won't output errors to a log file.

background.php is executed in the background when a user submits a form.

This is the script that runs after the user has submitted the form (this is not the background script):

```
# Execute the script in the background Linux style. Writes errors to a log file.
exec("php -f background.php 2>&1 &", $error_result);
# If $error_result is not empty, there was an error (2>&1).
if(!empty($error_result))
{
    # If $error_result is an array, convert it to a string seperated by PHP End of Line.
    if(is_array($error_result))
    {
        $error_result=implode(PHP_EOL, $error_result);
    }
    # Get the Logger Class.
    require_once Utility::locateFile(MODULES.'Logger'.DS.'Logger.php');
    # Create a new Logger object, and set the log file to use.
    $logger_obj=new Logger('command_line.log');
    # Write exec() output to log file.
    $logger_obj->writeLogFile($error_result);
    # Close log file.
    $logger_obj->closeLogFile();
}
```

The above script works, but the page hangs until the background script has finished.

**EDIT:** So, I gather from the answers and comments there is no way to do this using the `$error_result` parameter, and my Logger class.

I am going to try to add a `try` and `catch` in the background.php and see if I can log the errors that way.

Comment: Are you trying to run background.php from background.php? Try initiating your background script from another script to check if your logging really works.

Comment: It certainly does not output errors, as you are redirecting STDERR to /dev/null by adding `2>&1`. Just change it to `2>/path/to/error.log`? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @AbhishekPatel background.php is executed in the background when a user submits a form. Logging works, the whole script works, except the page hangs until the background script is finished. I want the web page to continue while the scripts runs in the background.

Comment: Just noticed your second parameter to exec(). Well, maybe just kill the `2>&1`  part then?

Comment: @ArSeN If I remove `2>&1` then I believe it will output everything, not just errors.

Comment: You "believe" wrong then. :P (imho) STDOUT and STDERR are different streams. Redirecting one does not necessarily mean redirecting the other.

Comment: @ArSeN I tried removing the `2>&1` but that did not work.

Comment: @Draven, yes, you can do error checking in `background.php`. Do you want to accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

still run `exec("php -f background.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");`

but in the file add:

```
ini_set("log_errors","1");
ini_set("error_log",'path/to/erroor.txt');
```

make sure you include a path if not the file will be created in the users home, the user will depend on how this is run (probably php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output error stream to an external log file, you can do it like this:

```
exec("php background.php 1>/dev/null 2>background.log &", $output, $error_code);
```

In this case we redirect STDOUT to `/dev/null` and STDERR to file `background.log`, and run `background.php` in background because of final `&`. You don't need `-f` option for php.

You can actually skip `$output` and `$error_code`. I included them here so I could explain that `$output` will always be empty array, and `$error_code` will always be 0. All they mean is that OS (Linux) successfully created another process in background.

Since 1) `background.php` is run in background and `exec` command will return immediately, and 2) `$output` and `$error_code` will not tell you if something went wrong, you would need to check for errors somewhere else by checking `background.log`.

Let me know if my explanation is not very clear, and I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use [`ignore_user_abort(true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

```
ignore_user_abort(true); 
set_time_limit(0);
```